# How do I get the recent json object based on datetime value?

Tags: python, json, datetime

Suppose I have json data where unique value in each record is datetime. How do I get the latest one?

Sample Json:

```
{ 
"jobs":
[
{
   id: 1,
   startTime: Wed 15 Jul 2015 15:39:33 GMT,
   somekey: someval,
   somekey: someval
},

{
   id:1,
   startTime: Sat 25 Jul 2015 02:37:50 GMT,
   somekey: someval,
   somekey: someval
}
]
}
```

Is there any way I can compare this datetime and with system datetime in python, figure out which is the recent record and return ONLY that record? I do not want to return based on the id here. If two datetimes are exact same, I want to return both those recent records. So far, I am able to sort the JSON data in the ascending time order. But I believe this approach is incorrect because JSON is always unordered. Any alternative way to do this? Or Can I return the last record in sorted data?

If the datetime format is in `%y-%m-%d`, It can be sorted using `.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'], '%Y-%m-%d'))` which works. However, I can't make out how to fetch the latest one if the time format is as given.

Comment: I found this on one of the stack overflow posts. 
`.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'], '%Y-%m-%d'))` This sorts the json in ascending order of time. However, I do not get how to get the last one which is the recent. I did not customise this on the json I've written above though. But that is the datetime format I want to deal with.

Comment: Always provide code in your question not in comments. Please update your question, so that others can see as well

Comment: @Utkarsh I've added details. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the json is as you have given above? According to that the datetime format you are using should not work.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I have written if datetime format is in `%y-%m-%d`, it does work. But I am confused on how to make get the latest for the given datetime format. Or, just simple as, how to get the last object in a json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for the date in format `'Sat 25 Jul 2015 02:37:50 GMT'` , you can use the following format string to parse the datetime using `strptime()` -

```
%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
```

Demo -

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed 15 Jul 2015 15:39:33 GMT','%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 15, 39, 33)
```

---

Secondly, It seems like the element with `jobs` key of the json dictionary has a list, and list has an order, you can sort that list (maybe using `sorted()` function, also it would be easier to sort in reverse order , so that it does not sort inplace) and then you can use -

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

To get the current time, and then iterating through the list , you can check for the first date (as the list is sorted in descending order) that is less than `now()` , and then keep iterating and taking the data until you find a date that is lower than it . This is assuming you can have dates in future as well.

Example -

```
import datetime
def get_most_recent(data):
    lst = data[jobs]
    newlst = sorted(lst,key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['startTime'],'%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'),reverse=True)
    recentdate = None
    nowd = datetime.datetime.now()
    retlist = []
    for i in newlst:
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(i['startTime'],'%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
        if recentdate is not None:
             if d == recentdate:
                 retlist.append(i)
             else:
                 break;
        elif d < nowd:
            recentdate = d
            retlist.append(i)
    return retlist
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Marking this one as correct because of details, much needed for a beginner like me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the dates using `key` attribute is a good idea.

I did the same but with `max()` in order to get the most recent data, and then returning all data with the same date.

```
from datetime import datetime 

def most_recent(data):
    dates = data["jobs"]
    recent = max(dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["startTime"], '%a %d %b %Y %X GMT'))["startTime"]
    return [d for d in dates if d["startTime"] == recent]
```

What you misunderstood is that indeed you can not sort dictionaries, but you can sort list containing dictionary-like objects.

If you look closer, your JSON data is a list of dictionaries, so it can easily be sorted as any other list object.